# Cast from object to function

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a javascript function of the form:

```
function(){alert("blah");}
```

Suppose I also have an applet, which has a method called doStuff that takes the function as a parameter:

```
MyApplet.doStuff(function(){alert("blah");});
```

Now suppose that the applet passes the function to a success or failure javascript callback function depending on the result of its calculations.  In that callback function, I want to execute the function so that the user gets my exceedingly informative "blah" message:

```
function callback(func) {
  func();
}
```

However, in the example above, func is no longer considered to be of type "function" (typeof func will return "object").  Is it possible to convert func to be a function so that it can be executed?  I have a number of hacks in mind that can give me what I want, but they are very ugly and I was hoping that I was missing something simple.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. How is `callback` itself passed around?

Comment: What is the content of this object passed by applet? Can you inspect it in firebug? If it has a `call()` or `apply()` function, you can try calling them.

Comment: The name of the callback function itself is passed to the applet as a parameter.  From there, I use the JSObject from the java plugin (netscape.javascript.JSObject) to call it and pass an object array containing the params.

Answer (score 3):

Try func.call()

Comment: If that works, then `typeof func` would be `"function"`, not `"object"` as in the OPs scenario.

Comment: I tried both func.call() and func.apply() and neither worked.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with FireBug (or some other debugger)?  Your statement above suggests your function should not be converted to an object; it might be enlightening to know exactly when this function ceases being a function.

Comment: The function is getting converted when the JSObject.call() method triggers.  It takes an array of Objects representing the parameters to the callback function.

Comment: So, if your JSObject was func, then the framework would call your func?

How about rather than passing a func to doStuff, you pass an object that includes func?  And then call obj.func()?

Answer (score 3):

Using the same style code as you already have, the following should alert "called!":

```
function callback(func){
  func();
}
callback(function(){
  alert("called!");
});
```

Is MyApplet.doStuff(function(){alert("blah");}); definitely passing its argument to the callback function unchanged?

Comment: Yes, from the applet to the callback function, the argument is unchanged in terms of content.  The only change is that now javascript interprets it as an object rather than a function.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to go for a different solution that isn't as ugly as I imagined it would be.  The JSObject.call() java method converts all the callback function parameters to plain jane objects.  So instead of passing:

```
function(){alert("blah")}
```

I now pass:

```
alert("blah")
```

or after some annoying escaping:

```
''alert(\''blah\'');''
```

Not so terrible eh?  Many thanks to everyone that offered their help, it is appreciated.